# How to get type annotations & attribute values for VariableElement with Java8?

Tags: java, annotation-processing

Consider the following code:

```
public class SimpleTest {

    private Map<@JSON Integer,Map<@Frozen Integer,@Enumerated(value = Enumerated.Encoding.NAME, test = "123") String>> map;
}
```

With the latest JDK8 API for annotation processing, how can I access the list of annotations (**@JSON**, **@Frozen** & **@Enumerated**) and their corresponding attributes (value & test for **@Enumerated**) from the VariableElement ?

```
final VariableElement mapElm = els.stream().filter(x -> x.getSimpleName().contentEquals("map")).findFirst().get();
???
???
```

I've tried many tricks, like `mapElm.getTypeArguments().get(0)` for the `@Json Integer` but I never succeed to get my hand on the annotation **@JSON**...

**Edit**: By accessing internal classes of the JDK, I can have access to those annotations but it's so hacky and sensitive to impl change that I'm wondering whether there is a better way

```
public static class SimpleEntityCodecFactoryTest {

    private Map<@JSON Integer,Map<@Frozen Integer,@Enumerated(value = Enumerated.Encoding.NAME, test = "123") String>> map;
}

final TypeElement typeElement = elementUtils.getTypeElement(SimpleEntityCodecFactoryTest.class.getCanonicalName());
final List<VariableElement> els = ElementFilter.fieldsIn(typeElement.getEnclosedElements());

final VariableElement mapElt = els.stream().filter(x -> x.getSimpleName().contentEquals("map")).findFirst().get();
final com.sun.tools.javac.util.List<Attribute.TypeCompound> typeAttributes = ((Symbol.VarSymbol) mapElt).getMetadata().getTypeAttributes();
for (Attribute.TypeCompound typeAttribute : typeAttributes) {
    final DeclaredType annotationType = typeAttribute.getAnnotationType();
    System.out.println(format("Accessing annotation '%s' at location : %s",annotationType.toString(),typeAttribute.getPosition().location));
    for (Map.Entry<Symbol.MethodSymbol,Attribute> entry : typeAttribute.getElementValues().entrySet()) {
        final Symbol.MethodSymbol methodSymbol = entry.getKey();
        final Attribute attribute = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println(format("Attribute '%s' for annotation '%s' : %s", methodSymbol.name, annotationType.toString(), attribute.toString()));
    }
}
```

The output display:

```
Accessing annotation 'info.archinnov.achilles.annotations.JSON' at location : TYPE_ARGUMENT(0)
Accessing annotation 'info.archinnov.achilles.annotations.Frozen' at location : TYPE_ARGUMENT(1),TYPE_ARGUMENT(0)
Accessing annotation 'info.archinnov.achilles.annotations.Enumerated' at location : TYPE_ARGUMENT(1),TYPE_ARGUMENT(1)
Attribute 'value' for annotation 'info.archinnov.achilles.annotations.Enumerated' : info.archinnov.achilles.annotations.Enumerated.Encoding.NAME
Attribute 'test' for annotation 'info.archinnov.achilles.annotations.Enumerated' : "123"
```

The above code is working fine in **IntelliJ**, but because of the dirty cast **((Symbol.VarSymbol) mapElt).getMetadata()**, it is working with **Oracle JDK** but fails miserably with **Eclipse compiler**.

Right now, I don't find any other solution than the dirty cast to access annotations in generic types. Any idea is welcomed

**Solution:**

Thanks to Werner (**wmdietl**), I can access the nested annotations using the **Tree API** instead of **Elements** or **TypeMirror**

However I'm quite stuck because once I get there, it is not possible to convert any subclass of **Tree** back to **Element** or **TypeMirror** (my real target).

All of my annotation processing is using heavily JavaPoet (https://github.com/square/javapoet) to generate clean source code and this framework only handles TypeMirror, not Tree

In the https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/blob/master/javacutil/src/org/checkerframework/javacutil/TreeUtils.java class, there are some methods to convert **Tree** back to **Element** but it is relying on **InternalUtils**, which I can't use because it won't be compatible with **Eclipse ECJ compiler**.

I  guess I will have to wait for JDK 9 before having an usable Element API that will be compatible with ECJ compiler

**Edit**: To make the type annotation work for **Eclipse Compiler**, I had to cast to internal compiler classes like here: https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles/blob/master/achilles-core/src/main/java/info/archinnov/achilles/internals/parser/AnnotationTree.java#L83-L85. It's ugly but that is the only way for now until JDK9.

Comment: I dug into into the code of the [checker-framework](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/) which is a good example of the annotation processor (it's the base of the JSR 308) and could not find a better way.
See their implementation of the type parameter : [here](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/blob/master/framework/src/org/checkerframework/framework/util/element/MethodTypeParamApplier.java#L60)

Comment: Btw, did you manage to trigger the getElementsAnnotatedWith method on your parameter to get a VariableElement ?
For me it seems an annotation with the target set to TYPE_PARAMETER is never passed to the processing round.
I had to registered on everything and then go down to the method.

Comment: "Btw, did you manage to trigger the getElementsAnnotatedWith method on your parameter to get a VariableElement ?" --> I'm dealing with VariableElement as **Class field**, not method parameter.

Comment: The handling of Class field is done here: https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/blob/master/framework/src/org/checkerframework/framework/util/element/TypeVarUseApplier.java#L184-L187

And they're doing an ugly casting from **VariableElement** to **Symbol. VarSymbol** and then call the internal method _getRawTypeAttributes()_ which is pretty equivalent to calling _getMetadata().getTypeAttributes()_

Comment: Cleanely getting type annotations from VariableElement does not seem to be possible in Java 8, but there is a [promising series of changes](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/anno-pipeline-dev/2015-April.txt) in Java 9 javac repository, so the situation may get better eventually.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't look at the Element (or Symbol), but at the TypeMirror (`javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror`).
The annotations you are interested in are type use annotations, so you can't access them (easily, there are hacky ways) through the Element.

Once you have the `TypeMirror`, you can use the methods in `javax.lang.model.AnnotatedConstruct` to query for all or particular annotations.

Another aspect to be aware of: usual annotation processing runs early in the compiler and not all types might have been set.
See
https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/blob/master/javacutil/src/org/checkerframework/javacutil/AbstractTypeProcessor.java
for a way to run your processor after code attribution.
Alternatively, you can use the new "plugin" mechanism in `com.sun.source.util.Plugin`, but that is OpenJDK specific.

Comment: I re-used the **AbstractTypeProcessor** from the checker framework. I put a break point at _final VariableElement mapElt_

there, I did **mapElt.asType().getAnnotationMirrors()** but it only returns me:

1. `@EmptyCollectionIfNull`
2. `@Frozen`

 All other annotations like `@Enumerated` etc ... are not returned

Comment: Element.asType doesn't return the type you would want https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#asType--

You should use the Tree and ask for the TypeMirror of the variable declaration.
If you send a complete example, I can have a look at what's happening.

Answer (score -3):

@JSON must be decorated with @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) so that Reflections can be used.

```
AnnotatedParameterizedType mapField = (AnnotatedParameterizedType)SimpleTest.class.getDeclaredFields()[0].getAnnotatedType();
AnnotatedType integerType = mapField.getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments()[0];

System.out.println(integerType.getAnnotations()[0]);
// -> @JSON()
```

see [AnnotatedParameterizedType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedParameterizedType.html)

Comment: The reflection API is useful for runtime introspection. I want to use **annotation processing** API at compile time.